# Create frame for dynamically created slide using CSS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For more info, please see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/).

I have successfully create a dynamic slides of DIV's.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>

</div>
```

and the js code is:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
```

and CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

What I want to happen is to have a border (can be a div with pure css) around the slide boxes so that I can't see the **transition animation at the sides**.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean. If you dont want to see the transitions, do you want the boxes to appear immediately instead of sliding?

Comment: Nope. I want to have a border or something around the slider.

Comment: Do you want to clip the slider on the center area?

Comment: yes. I want it to be like in an iframe.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/6279/

Comment: Thanks @bfavaretto, you can post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just throw a mask around it then position the mask for instance something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gUAXD/1/

This should work pretty much like an iframe due to the overflow:hidden.

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    margin-left:-1px;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 0%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}
#mask{
    border:3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="mask">
       <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
       <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
       <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
       <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
       <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```